# Behavior of DECDHL on single lines

Tags: terminal, dec, vt100

The escape sequences `ESC # 3` and `ESC # 4` (DECDHL) are meant to be used on pairs on adjacent lines to request double height lines. As an example:

```
echo -e "\e#3DOUBLE HEIGHT LINE\n\e#4DOUBLE HEIGHT LINE"
```

Now different terminal emulators behave differently when only a single line is set to double height. xterm happily displays the corresponding half of the double height characters, while konsole < 21.08 displays the whole double height characters.

What did real VTxxx do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What did real VTxxx do?

Certainly the VT220 does the same as what xterm does. It just shows the top or bottom half of the character. I don't recall this behaviour depending on the emulation mode.

I'm assuming the other VT's do the same as the VT220. It'd make for much simpler implementation.

Comment: Yes, the VT100 did.

Comment: I have a real VT100, and have written a simulator running the firmware.  I can confirm this answer is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Text-based VT-series terminals divide the screen into horizontal stripes whose height is that of a single text line, and generate the video output for each stripe independently.  Once a stripe is completed, the rendering hardware will "forget" everything about it as it fetches data describing how to render next stripe.

When rendering text to a bitmap display, as a GUI-based terminal emulator would have to do, it is often easier to draw a line of text without clipping than to show just the top half or just the bottom half.  That's probably the reason for the cited behavior.  On an actual text-based terminal, however, a line marked as the top or bottom half of a double-height line would be rendered without regard for how any previous lines had been formatted, since taking the formatting of previous lines into consideration would have made things more complicated.